# Download Linked File using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm new to selenium and I'm trying to use it to pull some data. Basically, my goal is to automate the downloading of tracks on SoundCloud using an external downloading tool. My goal is to navigate through a website, and then right click on a button on the final page and select "Download Linked File." Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

def gettrackfeatures(track):
    browser = webdriver.Safari()
    browser.get('https://scdownloader.net')
    print("Starting Page:", browser.current_url)
    maininput = browser.find_element_by_id('songURL')

    maininput.send_keys(track)

    button = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button.secondary')
    button.click()
    sleep(5)
    print("One Click:", browser.current_url)

    button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="results-wrapper"]/a''')
    ActionChains.context_click(button).perform()
    sleep(5)
    print("Two Clicks:", browser.current_url)

    browser.quit()

gettrackfeatures("https://soundcloud.com/rickyxsan/1nsane")
```

I found some other questions which lead me to try action chains, but I keep getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-acee249e870f> in <module>()
     33 
     34 
---> 35 gettrackfeatures("https://soundcloud.com/rickyxsan/1nsane")

<ipython-input-23-acee249e870f> in gettrackfeatures(track)
     24 
     25     button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="results-wrapper"]/a''')
---> 26     ActionChains.context_click(button).perform()
     27     sleep(5)
     28     print("Two Clicks:", browser.current_url)

//anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py in context_click(self, on_element)
    136            If None, clicks on current mouse position.
    137         """
--> 138         if self._driver.w3c:
    139             self.w3c_actions.pointer_action.context_click(on_element)
    140             self.w3c_actions.key_action.pause()

AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute '_driver'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, after you get the element with xpath `//*[@id="results-wrapper"]/a` you can simple call the `.click`.

An advise: instead of to use the `sleep(5)`, try always to use the [explicit waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits).

[Here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) a link with all the expected conditions that you could use.

The entire code:

```
driver.get("https://scdownloader.net")
track="https://soundcloud.com/rickyxsan/1nsane"

maininput = driver.find_element_by_id('songURL')
maininput.send_keys(track)
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.secondary')
button.click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
downloadButton= wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='results-wrapper']/a")))
downloadButton.click()
```

Comment: When I click the final download button on the final page, it takes me to a page where it starts streaming the song. Normally, when I'm on that final page, I have to right click on the download button and select "Download Linked File," can I download the file from this streaming page?

Comment: @KyleFrye I tried with Chrome and Firefox and it works. With Safari, is opened the stream instead of to download the file. You could get the link to the file (that is in the "href" attribute) and try to download it with curl or with urllib. I don't know if there is a solution with Safari.

Comment: I hadn't considered that the browser would be the problem, changing to Chrome fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
ActionChains.context_click(button).perform()
```

Try to use :

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
#your other lines of code
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.context_click(button).perform()
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response! So when I run this it brings up the context menu, but doesn't do it on top of the button, so I can't navigate to the "Download Linked File" option.

Comment: @KyleFrye Well, I took care of your elementary issue of initiating the`ActionChain` class. You can go ahead and add the click event to the chain as well. Please `Accept` the `Answer` if it has addressed your `Question`.